# How to run all ruby files in specified directory with rake

Tags: ruby, testing, directory, rake

I have installed, Ruby 1.8.7, ci_reporter 1.8.4, test unit 2.5.4, rake 10.0.3.

My testA.rb, testB.rb ... testZ.rb :

```
require 'includeA.rb'
require 'includeB.rb'
require 'includeC.rb'
require 'includeD.rb'

Begin of the code...
... End of the code
```

Here my rakefile :

```
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rubygems'
gem 'ci_reporter'
gem 'test-unit' 
require 'test/unit' 
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit'  

task :default => [:test]

task :test do
  sh "ruby -I E:/pathToIncludesA/" " -I E:/pathToIncludesB/" " -I E:/pathToIncludesC/" " -I E:/pathToIncludesD/" " E:/pathToTests/testA.rb"
  sh "ruby -I E:/pathToIncludesA/" " -I E:/pathToIncludesB/" " -I E:/pathToIncludesC/" " -I E:/pathToIncludesD/" " E:/pathToTests/testB.rb"
  ...
  sh "ruby -I E:/pathToIncludesA/" " -I E:/pathToIncludesB/" " -I E:/pathToIncludesC/" " -I E:/pathToIncludesD/" " E:/pathToTests/testZ.rb"
end
```

And I launch the test execution with :

```
rake CI_REPORTER=reports test
```

All works fine, but now a lot of tests will be added in my "pathToTest" and now I would like to run all the tests but with a single cmd in my rakefile.

I try this from a windows batch cmd : `for /r  "E:\ExempleOfTests\" %%i in (*.rb) do ruby "%%i"`

It runs all the .rb files in the folder ExempleOfTests.

So now I am refactoring my rakefile, trying to incorporate the windows batch cmd.

Here my new rakefile :

```
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rubygems'
gem 'ci_reporter'
gem 'test-unit' 
require 'test/unit' 
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit'  

task :default => [:test]

task :test do
  sh "for /r E:/pathToTests/ %%i in (*.rb) do ruby -I E:/pathToIncludesA/ -I E:/pathToIncludesB/ -I E:/pathToIncludesC/ -I E:/pathToIncludesD/ %%i"
end
```

But my output console when I launch with "rake CI_REPORTS=reports test" :

```
unexpected %%i
rake aborted
commande failed with status (1) ...
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can run it like this:

```
find path/to/test/folder -name '*_test.rb' | xargs -n1 -I{} bundle exec ruby -Itest {}
```

and then wrap it into rake task if you want.